# Grails gorm query question

Tags: grails, grails-orm

having the domain classes:

```
class A {

 Date dateCreated
 static hasMany = [b:B]
 ...

}

class B {

  String name
  String value
...

}
```

What createCriteria or HQL query can I use to return a list with:

- A's creation date
- B's value for A with the name entry set to 'X'

Note: Although there's no explicit constraint, there's only one "value" for each 'X' and a combination.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HQL would be

```
def results = A.executeQuery(
    'select a.id, a.dateCreated, b from A a inner join a.b b ' +
    'where b.name=:name',
    [name: 'X'])
```

This will give you a `List` of 3-element `Object[]` arrays containing `A.id`, `A.dateCreated`, and the list of `B` instances. I added the id to the query so you can group by it client-side:

```
def grouped = results.groupBy { it[0] }
```

This will be a `Map` where the keys are the `A` ids and the values are the `List`s from the original results.

Ideally you'd do the grouping at the database, but it would complicate the query, and assuming you don't have a large number of results it should be fast.